# insert a humidity sensor into mplab

Tags: c, mplab

I have to implement an assignment with PIC24FJ1024GB610 and above the other peripherals I have to add a humidity sensor like HIH-4030/31, I also have to use the built-in temperature sensor. I installed the relatice 16bit compiler for c and mplab x ide 5.45, and tried to find the peripheral from mcc but I can;t.Also I can't find any repository with the c headers and .c files to import them into the project.How can I add on mplab a humidity sensor while there is no bulit-in sensor on mcc?

Comment: yes but mplab has already implenetation for c the peripherals.

Comment: I have to add the relative libraries and then implenent the whole requirements

Comment: How can I add on mplab a humidity sensor while there is no bulit-in sensor on mcc.That is what I am asking for.

Comment: then edit your post ... remove `Any suggestion?` ......... and insert `How can I add on mplab a humidity sensor while there is no bulit-in sensor on mcc?`